# Are the 1-dimensional subspaces sums direct?

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

Suppose we have 1-dimensional subspaces $U_1, U_2$ of  $V = \mathbb{R^{3}}$ spanned by $U_1 = (1,2,0), U_2 = (1,1,1)$. Is the sum $U_1$ + $U_2$ direct?

I first stated that $U_1 \cap U_2$ = (0,0,0) if it is a direct sum, but I am not sure with what to say about the sum $U_1$ + $U_2$ = (2,3,1) and how to tell if its unique or not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, the sum is direct because the intersection is the trivial space. In fact You must impose

$\lambda \cdot (1,2,0)=\mu\cdot (1,1,1)$

and it is clear this holds only if $\mu=\lambda=0$

At this point, if you want to find generators for the sum space, will be

$U_1+U_2=\langle \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix} \rangle$

In your case it is simple to see what it’s happening:

$\langle v\rangle$ is the line generated by the vector $v$ and so it is clear that your two no-proportional vectors $v, w$ generate two lines for which the intersection is only $0$ and such that their sum is the plane generated by the two vectors.

Comment: Why is the intersection the trivial space if both $U_1$ and $U_2$ have the same first element, 1? Also, one of the conditions for the direct sum is for the sum to be unique, so how do we know $U_1$ + $U_2$ is  unique? or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: @user728655 What are you saying? I didn’t understand

Comment: You said the intersection is the trivial space, but the first element of $U_1$ and $U_2$ are the same, so shouldn't the intersection be (1,0,0)?

Comment: @user728655 It's important to distinguish between the vectors $v_1 = (1, 2, 0)$, $v_2 = (1, 1, 1)$ and the subspaces $U_1 = \langle v_1 \rangle$, $U_2 = \langle v_2 \rangle$ that they span.  The intersection of $U_1$ and $U_2$ (the subspaces, not the vectors) is the set of all vectors that are scalar multiples of both $v_1$ and $v_2$.  The only such vector is $(0, 0, 0) = 0v_1 = 0v_2$.